# Run-time error '1004' Method 'Save' of object '_Workbook' failed

Tags: vba, excel

I got this error while running an VBA application. I think this error is related to the following line in my code

```
ActiveWorkbook.Save
```

This is the whole code.

```
LDate = Date
LDate = Mid(LDate, 4, 2)
If LDate > 8 Then
Sheets("a").Cells(13, "H").Value = Sheets("a").Cells(13, "H").Value + 1000
Else
Sheets("a").Cells(13, "H").Value = Sheets("a").Cells(13, "H").Value + 1
End If
ActiveWorkbook.Save
```

Can someone explain the cause of this error and how I can tackle it.

Please read below comments.

This is the subroutine that is getting executed when the first button is clicked.

```
Sub import()
Dim Filt As String
Dim FilterIndex As Integer
Dim Title As String
Dim FileName As Variant
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim alldata As String
Dim temp As String
Dim oFSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim oFS As TextStream

'Filt = "Cst Files (*.txt),*.txt"
'Title = "Select a cst File to Import"
'FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:=Filt, Title:=Title)
'If FileName = False Then
'MsgBox "No File Was Selected"
'Exit Sub
'End If

'Call TestReference

' Open the file dialog
Set diaFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
diaFolder.AllowMultiSelect = False
diaFolder.Show
If diaFolder.SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
folderpath = diaFolder.SelectedItems(1)
folderpath = folderpath & "\"
'MsgBox diaFolder.SelectedItems(1)

Set diaFolder = Nothing

'RefreshSheet
On Error Resume Next
temp = folderpath & "*.txt"
sFile = Dir(temp)

Do Until sFile = ""
inputRow = Sheets("RawData").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
FileName = folderpath & sFile
Set oFS = oFSO.OpenTextFile(FileName)
Dim content As String
    content = oFS.ReadAll
content = Mid(content, 4, Len(content) - 3)
With Sheets("RawData").Range("A" & inputRow)
        .NumberFormat = "@"
        .Value = content
End With

oFS.Close
Set oFS = Nothing

alldata = ""
finalrow = Sheets("RawData").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("RawData").Activate
For i = inputRow To finalrow
alldata = alldata & Cells(i, "A").Value & " "
Cells(i, "A").Value = ""
Next i
Cells(inputRow, "B").Value = alldata

temp = StrReverse(FileName)
temp = Left(temp, InStr(1, temp, "\") - 1)
temp = StrReverse(temp)
temp = Left(temp, InStr(1, temp, ".") - 1)
Cells(inputRow, "A").Value = temp
Sheets("RawData").Cells(inputRow, "A").NumberFormat = "@"
sFile = Dir()
Loop
Else
MsgBox ("No Folder Selected")
End If
End Sub
```

How to make this code stop accessing the worksheet after executing this macro?

Comment: Are you opening a previously-saved file (for example: myMacro.xlsm) or are you just starting Excel and writing this code in the popup file?

Comment: What happens when you click the save icon on the workbook manually?

Comment: @varocarbas I am opening a previously saved file.

Comment: @GrahamAnderson When I click the save icon, nothing particular happens other than saving itself.

Comment: When this error comes, I click the save icon. Next time the macro runs without any error.

Comment: And the previously saved file has a macro-supporting format (like xlsm), isn't it?

Comment: I've tried your code and can't reproduce your error.

Comment: @varocarbas I didn't understand you. I have a worksheet("First") with 2 buttons. When I click on the first button,it copies data from text files into rows in another sheet("Second"). When I click the second button,the code shown above is executed. Along with that some more codes are executed to perform some functions on the data in sheet ("Second")

Comment: @GrahamAnderson May be because its not the only macro in the sheet.

Comment: I meant the file type. The (saved) Excel file containing the macro has a right type/extension, isn't it? For example: book1.xlsx is not valid because does not support macros; book1.xlsm is valid.

Comment: @varocarbas Ofcourse the Excel File is saved as .xlsm (Macro Enabled Workbook)

Comment: Which worksheet functions are you using? Are you using any event handlers like `Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave`

Comment: Of course you shouldn't be getting this error when using .Save properly :) Then the given file might be used by another process (or by the macro itself from a different part). As a quick test, please, create a new macro consisting exclusively in ActiveWorkbook.Save. If it works, the problem is in other part of your code (please, post more); if it does not work, it would mean that this file is being accessed from somewhere else/you don't have permissions to save it (please, stop accessing this file from somewhere else or get permission :))

Comment: @varocarbas I have edited the question. Please see it. How to know if this code (last posted)is still accessing the sheet?

Comment: @GrahamAnderson I'm not using any such even handlers I think.

Comment: This code is not doing anything which should lock the given file (and trigger the error). If you run this code from a proper file (book1.xlsm) and write ActiveWorkbook.Save at the end, everything should be fine. I have run this code in my computer without any problem. You are opening files but are .txt files and the lines involving Sheets("RawData") are completely "inoffensive". There has to be something else: either other part of your code (you are still posting fragments) other process accessing the file, or not enough permissions or something on these lines.

Comment: @varocarbas The other code is lengthy. Shall i post it here.

Comment: Better analyse it and post the bits which have higher chances of being responsible of the problem; that is: parts analysing xlsm files, any action on the given file/Excel Object which might lock the access (e.g., renaming, moving, etc.). Or you might do a step-by-step execution by your own: copy the problematic line in different parts of your code and see where the error is triggered and where is not; in this way you should be able to quickly locate the responsible bit.

Comment: @varocarbas The thing is the code I posted first here comes first in that second macro. So I don't think there will be any problem in the rest of the code. Is there any chance that the error part comes after the line?

Comment: @varocarbas That error is not showing anymore when i executed last three times. I will post if it appears again.

Comment: Regarding your first question: the first code you posted cannot block file. To your last comment: this behaviour does not make any sense (unless you have changed the code) and usually (99.999999999953% of the cases :)) indicates that you were looking in the wrong place: the code wasn't responsible for the error; what means that you were locking this file from somewhere else. Compare what you were doing before against what you are doing now and will find what was locking the file.

Answer (score 4):

Although I think you should **seriously consider refactoring your code**, you should begin by referencing the correct workbook called by the .Save() Method.

```
    Workbooks("Insert_Workbook_Name_Here.xlsm").Save
```

Make sure that the workbook name and extension (.xlsm, .xls, .xlsx) match the file you are actually trying to save.

Comment: I will consider this while coding.Thank you.

Comment: This is actually bad code... Hard-coding the workbook file name into code is bad practice. Use codenames where possible. WorkbookCodeName.Save is better

Answer (score 0):

This error happened in a macro that I wrote as well. I have this code to close a dialogue box.

```
Private Sub CancelButton_Click()
   Unload Me
ThisWorkbook.Save
   End
End Sub
```

I received the same error because the workbook that was being loaded was from a "last saved" copy due to an update reboot that happened while the original was open. Not sure how to avoid that in the future but thought it might be helpful to someone.